# How can I trust my correlation analysis if it changes dramatically with just single values being added or removed?

Tags: correlation

I did an experiment and obtained the following values which I want to correlate to see if there is a connection between sampling method A and method B.

A,B
Pair 1: 4000,3500
Pair 2: 1500,40000
Pair 3: 5000,4500
Pair 4: 2500,7000
Pair 5: 1000,1000
Pair 6: 12000,17000
Pair 7: 2000,2000
Pair 8: 4000,40000
Pair 9: 13000,25000
**Pair 10: 52000,365500**
**Pair 11: 178000,23000**
Pair 12: 9500,19000
Pair 13: 4000,18500
Pair 14: 37000,2000
Pair 15: 7000,13000
Pair 16: 5000,34000
Pair 17: 5500,41000

I get a non-significant correlation of R = 0.196. But when I remove a single pair, for example to exclude outliers this result changes dramatically:

- removing Pair 10 gives me a R value of 0.046.
- removing Pair 11 gives me a R value of 0.759, a spectacular correlation!

What is wrong here? How can I trust my analysis if a single value changes the result so much? Are there some assumptions I didn't comply with? Can I only do correlations if values are roughly of the same dimension?

Comment: This is an influence function approach.  You can see my paper in the American Journal of Mathematical and Management Science(1983) the form of the influence function for Pearson's bivariate correlation. The journal is currently managed by Taylor and Francis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can't trust the correlation simply because of the sample size - it's too small. Here's what MATLAB is telling you:

```
>> [rho,pval]=corr(a(:,2),a(:,3))

rho =

    0.1960


pval =

    0.4509

>> [rho,pval]=corr(a(:,2),a(:,3),'type','Kendall')

rho =

    0.2556


pval =

    0.1716
```

The output shows you the correlation and its p-value. In the first test I'm using usual linear correlation (Pearson), and correlation comes low and not significant.

In the second case I use Kendall's with the same conclusion. With Kendall you don't assume the linear relationship, which could be important in your case because Pair 10-11 observations seem to stick out. This could be because there's a nonlinear relationship.

However a scatter plot below would suggest that there might be an outlier in your data. So, you have to go back to your data and try to understand what's up with Pairs 10-11. I doubt this can be done statistically, you need to understand the data and how it was acquired etc. It's outside statistics

[image]